# Swift Facebook login with Firebase sdk is not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase

I'm developing app which uses Firebase.
I tried to login with facebook with firebase sdk but I can't catch event when user finishes authentication with facebook.
With my code, Nothing is printed.
Event `print("checking")` is not working.

```
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://nos.firebaseio.com/users")
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()



    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
        (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        print("checking")
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                    }
            })
        }
    })
```

I'm using the latest version of xcode(7.2).
Is there anybody who has experience in this?
I'm looking for your answer.

Comment: Since you say `checking` doesn't even print, I'm going to assume the problem is unrelated to Firebase. You might want to prove my assumption and reduce the code based on that. It'll make it clearer in which direction you (and those who can help) need to look.

Comment: Did you enable Facebook Authentication in your App Dashboard? Also, did you update your app's .plist file with your Facebook AppID and other criteria? Also, check to see if your AppDelegate has the correct redirects (if required)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your ref.

Try it without the /users

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://nos.firebaseio.com")
```

The rest of the login function works fine.

Comment: All that changed is that you removed `users`, right? Because that (although certainly neater) should not make any difference.

Comment: @AMG Hi, I also tried that. But same thing happens. When user presses 'Okay' button in facebook authentication it came back to app. But nothing happens. And even nothing printed.